# Listening to, and changing tracks on another PC on a LAN?

Tags: 10.04, rhythmbox, networking

Rhythmbox runs on a PC in my network, and I was wondering if it would be possible to change the track, volume etc from my pc? Both PCs run 10.04.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do this; here are a few of them:

### Web interface

Easy, convenient, cross-compatible, but hard to bind media keys.

- [Rythmweb](http://web.vee.net/projects/rhythmweb/)
- [rythmote](http://code.google.com/p/rhythmote/)

### SSH + Scripting

Very lightweight option.

- [rythmbox-client](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/rhythmbox-client.1.html)
- [amixer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer)

### MPD

This involves switching to an entirely different application than Rythmbox, but it may be worth considering if you have a setup in which you would usually prefer to control music remotely.

- [MPD Wiki](http://mpd.wikia.com/wiki/Music_Player_Daemon_Wiki)

### XMMS2

Similar to MPD; not as widely used but more recent.

- [XMMS2 Wiki](http://xmms2.org/wiki/Main_Page)

### Remote Desktop/VNC

A little overkill unless you regularly have a session running anyway or very rarely control your media remotely.

- [Ubuntu Documentation: VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)

Comment: I really think @jamie-schembri did a nice answer here! But just to complement it, here is a tutorial about manage Rhythmbox using ssh conection (no need to install 3rd parts): http://xuedi.de/blog/2010/04/08/remote-control-rhythmbox/

Answer (score 2):

You can use remote desktop for that.Goto Applications>>Internet>>Terminal Server Client

[image]

Enter the ip address of the computer running rythmbox,and click connect.It will prompt for user and password,enter the details and your connection will be established.Now you can change the volume or track or whatever you wish.

Comment: I've no doubt that this works, but it does seem like using a sledgehammer to kill fleas.

Comment: ERROR: Channel_register, WARNING: Initializing sound-support  failed, ERROR: Unable to connect is what I get. Removed the sound option from connections, and now I get a ERROR: Unable to connect.

Comment: `@Kaustubh P` I think it may be an issue with your firewall which is blocking the port.

Answer (score 1):

If your music library exists on another PC/server and you want to play those tracks you can also use the DAAP protocol to stream the audio to a client running locally

First setup a server: http://www.fireflymediaserver.org/
Then use a daap-client (e.g. rhythmbox , banshee, itunes, amarok), to listen to the audio stream on your PC.