# How to use rhythmbox-client on LAN?

Tags: rhythmbox, networking

A few days ago I had asked this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14844/listening-to-and-changing-tracks-on-another-pc-on-a-lan), and according to one suggestion, used rhythmote. It is a web-interface to change songs on a rhythmbox playing on some PC. However, its not what I had thought of, and I stumbled upon documentation for rhythmbox-client. I tried a few ways of using it, but was unsuccessful. Let me show you a few ways of how I did it. The rhythmbox is running at address 192.168.1.4, lets call it jukebox.

#### Passing the address as a parameter

Hoping that I would be able to see and browse through songs on the jukebox

`rhythmbox-client 192.168.1.4`

But, I get this message

> (rhythmbox-client:8370):
>   Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Did not receive
>   a reply. Possible causes include: the
>   remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy
>   blocked the reply, the reply timeout
>   expired, or the network connection was
>   broken.
>
> (rhythmbox-client:8370):
>   Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Did not receive
>   a reply. Possible causes include: the
>   remote application did not send a
>   reply, the message bus security policy
>   blocked the reply, the reply timeout
>   expired, or the network connection was
>   broken.

#### SSH

`ssh -l jukebox 192.168.1.4`

`rhythmbox-client --print-playing`

Which spat this at me:

> (rhythmbox-client:9389): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.

#### rhythmbox-client as root

`gksudo rhythmbox-client 192.168.1.4`

A rhythmbox client comes up, but with no music shown in the library. I am guessing this is running on my own computer.

Can anyon tell me how rhythmbox-client is to be run, and is it even correct of me to think that I can get a rhythmbox window showing the songs **on the** jukebox?

PS: There were a few other solutions mentioned, but I want to evaluate each and every one of them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, you need to grep the actual dbus-session of the machine that runs rythmbox. This is kind of tricky.
I have installed a script at my server, which is run after boot automatically, and which saves the current dbus-address to a file in my homedir.

If I ssh to the machine later, I can just grep the session-adress from there.

I: Script to store dbus adress:
name it "Get.Dbus.sh" and save it somewhere to your disk. Give it the following content:

```
set | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > ~/.DBUS_temp
```

make it executable and add it to your start-items

II: Script to grep the current session:
name it "Run.DBus.sh" and save it in e.g. /usr/local/bin/

Give it the following content:

```
source /home/YOUR_USERNAME/.DBUS_temp
export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
$*
```

don't forget to make it executable

III: ssh to your machine and start the rhythmbox-client as follows:

```
Run.DBus.sh rhythmbox-client
```

This works here!

Comment: Please Note: Steps I and II need to be done at the SERVER (the machine that runs rhythmbox)!!!

Comment: The machine is no longer at my disposal, so I cannot try your solution. I set them up with Remote Desktop Viewer and the people are happy.

Answer (score 2):

When you try it over SSH, first run

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

or else it will try to start a new instance of Rhythmbox via your SSH session, rather than connecting to the Rhythmbox you already have running on x server display 0.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if my answer will help you out, but a great way I use Rhythmbox to stream music around the house is via DAAP. You can enable that plug-in (if not enabled already), and with that just open up Rhythmbox on another computer and your computer with all the songs will show up on the left pane. Click on that computer (enter in password if you have put one), and stream your music! It's that easy, but you have to have Rhythmbox running on the both computers. Oh and also you need to open up port number 3689 in your firewall (if you have firewall enabled) in the computer that will stream the music as incoming.

Answer (score 0):

Can anyon tell me how rhythmbox-client is to be run, and is it even correct of me to think that I can get a rhythmbox window showing the songs on the jukebox?

> You can achieve this if you are forwarding X is enabled `ForwardX11 yes` is in your config file in your ~/.ssh directory

So if you are able to launch rhythm box on your computer you should be able to launch it on your computer with Forwarding X back to the pc you are accessing it on. IT should be simple as that. I managed to do the same thing with virtual box on server I run headlessly.