# Does RhythmBox have any command line interface or method of interprocess communication?

Tags: command-line, rhythmbox, music, banshee, music-player

I'd really like to communicate with rhythmbox with a web server so I can remotely change the music playing from my smartphone. Is there a command-line interface for rhythmbox to do things like the following (fictional) commands?

```
rhythmbox next
rhythmbox shuffle=false
rhythmbox change album='Dark Side of the Moon' artist='Pink Floyd' song='Time'
```

Is there a socket or message-passing interface instead? Are there any substitute programs that could get the job done, like Banshee, or some other type of server?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/21494/how-to-use-rhythmbox-client-on-lan

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/150790/how-do-i-run-a-script-on-a-dbus-signal

Comment: @foss no, none of the questions has a similar answer as Geppetos.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically, the short answer is "Yes" and the complement of such answer will be "Use the `rhythmbox-client` command from a terminal in order to control your current running Rhythmbox, if it is not already loaded the first instance of your commands will invoke it."

In example: `rhythmbox-client --play` will make the current Rhythmbox session to start playing the current song (or the first song in the list). If Rhythmbox is closed then it will open it first in order to start playing.

Further information about the `rhythmbox-client` and its usage can be reached in the **[rhythmbox-client man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/rhythmbox-client.1)**. I place here a portion of the manpage just for reference.

```
NAME
       rhythmbox-client - controls a running instance of rhythmbox

SYNOPSIS
       rhythmbox-client [option...][file...]

DESCRIPTION
       rhythmbox-client  is a tool for controlling an already running instance
       of  rhythmbox.   It's  useful  for  remote  control  scripting,  adding
       specific  files  to  the library from the shell, or printing details of
       what's playing. It also has an interactive mode, useful for controlling
       playback  remotely  via  ssh.  Any  files  specified  after  the option
       arguments will be added to the library.  If  the  --enqueue  option  is
       given, the files will also be added to the play queue.

OPTIONS
       -?,--help
              Show help options

       --debug
              Enable debug output

       --no-start
              Do not start a new instance of rhythmbox

       --quit Quit rhythmbox

       -i,--interactive
              Start  interactive  mode  --no-present Don't present an existing
              rhythmbox window

       --next Jump to next song

       --previous
              Jump to previous song

       --play Resume playback if currently paused

       --pause
              Pause playback if currently playing

       --play-pause
              Toggle play/pause mode

       --stop Stop playback if currently playing

       --play-uri=URI
              Play a specified URI, importing it if necessary

       --enqueue
              Add specified tracks already in the library to the play queue

       --clear-queue
              Empty the play queue before adding new tracks

       --print-playing
              Print the title and artist of the playing song

       --print-playing-format=format
              Print formatted details of the song (see FORMAT OPTIONS below).

       --set-volume
              Set the playback volume

       --volume-up
              Increase the playback volume

       --volume-down
              Decrease the playback volume

       --print-volume
              Print the current playback volume

       --select-source=URI
              Select the source corresponding to a URI (device or mount point)

       --activate-source=URI
              Select the source corresponding to a URI (device or mount point)
              and start playing from it if not already playing.

       --play-source=URI
              Select the source corresponding to a URI (device or mount point)
              and start playing from it.

FORMAT OPTIONS
       %at    album title

       %aa    album artist

       %aA    album artist (lowercase)

       %as    album artist sortname

       %aS    album artist sortname (lowercase)

       %ay    album year

       %ag    album genre

       %aG    album genre (lowercase)

       %an    album disc number

       %aN    album disc number, zero padded

       %st    stream title

       %tn    track number (i.e 8)

       %tN    track number, zero padded (i.e 08)

       %tt    track title

       %ta    track artist

       %tA    track artist (lowercase)

       %ts    track artist sortname

       %tS    track artist sortname (lowercase)

       %td    track duration

       %te    track elapsed time

       Variables can be combined using quotes. For example "%tn %aa %tt", will
       print  the  track  number  followed  by the artist and the title of the
       track.

AUTHOR
       This manual page was written by Sven Arvidsson  <sa@whiz.se>,  for  the
       Debian system (but may be used by others).
```

## Edit

I got some interest on this subject so I ran a test with the next command:

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.rhythmbox /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Seek int64:60000000
```

From the original answer posted right here. Which indeed works for the task of seeking on current playing song, (based on the asker's comment).

Good luck!

Comment: Awesome! That saves me so much headache. Do you know if there's a `--seek` ability? It doesn't include it in the man pages.

Comment: Unfortunately the rhythmbox-client options are limited. I have added the details to this answer for your convenience.

Comment: Take a look on this answer: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75680, the former --seek option seems to have been deprecated but it seems there is another solution. Please let us know if you succeed. Thank you.

Comment: Oh well... I dropped another edit for you. Good luck!

Comment: It turns out Banshee has the ability to both query for current player information (like track playing, cursor position, player state, etc.) and control playback! `banshee --help` 'splains it all! Thank you for your help though, I hope you have a great day!

Comment: Well, your question was about Rhythmbox, that's why I mainly focused on it. And yes, today I have learned something new. Thank you! :D

Comment: Is there any way I can get the filename of the currently playing song?

Comment: Hello @Asattar, Yeah, sure. You can. Simply drop `rhythmbox-client --print-playing` in a terminal and you will receive the current playing song name with the artist name included. If you wish just a parameter, let's say: only the song name, just use the `--print-playing-format` and use the format options mentioned in this answer. Like: `rhythmbox-client --print-playing-format %tt` which will result in just the song name as a result in the terminal. Good luck!

Comment: @GeppettvsD'Constanzo I've looked into all the format options but I cannot find one that gives me the filename e.g. `/home/abdulsattar/Music/song.mp3`. I need this because I can write a small shellscript that can delete the currently playing song.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry. Didn't understand that. I will look for it and drop an edit for you when I find it. Sorry again.

Comment: I was unable to find anything from the command line client. There exists a DBus method (in `org.gnome.Rhythmbox /org/gnome/Rhythmbox/Player`) however. Unfortunately, there exists a new service (`org.gnome.Rhythmbox3`) in Ubuntu 13.10 and I am unable to find any method that gives me the currently playing URI.